# Prove that we have at least one set with at least $4$ red dots.

Tags: combinatorics

We have a set of points, some of which are red.  We form sets $A_{1},A_{2},...,A_{68}$ so that each set has exactly $5$ points, of which at least one is red. Moreover, any triplet in the set of points is in exactly one set. Prove that we have at least one set with at least $4$ red dots.

The hint in the book is counting in two ways.

Comment: I am confused with "any triplet in the set of points is in exactly one set", since there is no $N$ so that $\binom{N}{3}=68$.

Comment: @Yuval You missed a term. Counting triplets in two ways we get ${5\choose 3}\cdot 68 = {N \choose 3}\implies N = 17$.

Comment: @JPMarciano I see, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $N$ be the number of points. Counting triplets in two ways we get ${5\choose 3}\cdot 68 = {N \choose 3}\implies N = 17$.

Let $R$ be the number of red points. Then, counting triplets with no red points we have ${17-R\choose 3}\leq 68\cdot {4\choose 3} \implies R\geq 5$.

At this point, I think that some Pigeonhole Principle argument will work.

Comment: If the conclusion is not true, the $\binom{R}{3}$ many red triples must appear in mutually different sets, these sets does not have none-red triples. And each of the other sets can contribute at most $4$ many non-red triples. So $\binom{17-R}{3}\leq (68-\binom{R}{3})4$.

Comment: @Yuval It doesn't give a contradiction yet, $R$ can be 5, 6 or 7 in this inequality.

Comment: When $R=5$, consider the triples with exactly two reds, that demands, apart from the $\binom{5}{3}$ sets, there are further sets that contain at least two reds, and  that decreases the supply of non-red triples. One may argue through this but it is a little ugly.